# django inheritance hurts my brain

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I'm making a beer website, and I'm stuck. I need to have a recipe that i can relate to many different ingredients. Is there a way to create a model "Ingredient", and inherit many different models: "Hop", "Grain", etc.  I would want to do this so I have my relationship between recipe and ingredient, and i don't have to create 100 different relationships to cover each kind of ingredient.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you saying you want a model called Hop, a model called Grain, and so on? Wouldn't you rather have a field for ingredient_type or something like that?

Comment: In general, you should have a separate model only if you need different code to work with it. It's unlikely that's the case between Hop and Grain, and it would be simpler to treat them as two types of ingredients (with an `ingredient_type` field distinguishing them)

Comment: They do have different fields, for instance I want the acid level of the hops, and I want the sugar potential of the grain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would personally advise against it in most cases since table inheritance is a pain (imho) in Django.

You can do it like this:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    recipes = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s')

class Hop(Ingredient):
    pass

class Grain(Ingredient):
    pass
```

Comment: It does sound like a pain, but the alternative of specifying hop_additions, grain_additions, etc for all 100 different types with different parameters sounds messy. Do I have any other options?

Comment: The alternative is as David Robinson specified, using a common Ingredient model and simply specifying the type. Querying something like this can be a pain since you have lots of different models to query separately.

Comment: One more clarification, What if i have two models that use ingredient, like Recipe and Log? Is there a way to setup my manytomany to handle multiple models?

Comment: @user1104922: there are 2 ways, with generic foreign keys and table inheritance. And both should be used as a last resort imho.